# Request: (Analytics) correlate the activities time (infer geographical region) with the quality of question

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to find correlations between the geographical regions and the quality (outcome) of questions, but without uniquely identifying any individuals, accounts or ids. Also, I am interested in the geographic correlation with tags, which may indicate the types of software and technology that is popular in those regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do offer the creative commons data dump:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/creative-commons-data-dump-jun-10/

However I can't think of any way to provide the identifying information you are requesting without sacrificing privacy.